# Vue-tabilator: How do I access the tabulator functions?

Tags: vue-component, nuxt.js, tabulator

I use Tabulator in my Nuxt.js project. I use Vue-Tabulator for it.

How I can get access by tabulator's functions in  Vue's component' methods?

Must I use Tabulator's instance through `this.$refs.tabulator.getInstance();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Vue Tabulator Documentation](https://vue-tabulator.netlify.com/guide/#advanced-interaction)

As you say, you must get the instance then you can call any of the Tabulator functions:

```
const tabulatorInstance = this.$refs.tabulator.getInstance();

//clear table data
tabulatorInstance.clearData();
```